# How do i sort an array based on one of its contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have an array that contains text and html. myarray[1] contains the following.. myarray[2] contains the same thing just different name 'john' and so on

```
153); color: white; cursor: pointer; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; font-family:
 Arial;" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor = 'white';  this.style.color='#336699'"
 onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor = ''; this.style.color = 'white'; " 
onclick="if(top.mail.checkDataset()) mail.execFunction('javascript: changeMain(\'orderCreate1.do\')')">

<img alt="" src="images/round-white-bullet.gif" height="10" width="10"> John<br>
```

how can i sort the whole array so that it ignores everything and sortsd by the name 'john' in this case? the names always come after the image and before the `br` if that helps

Comment: please make your post legible.

Comment: Do you mean a single array element has all that markup? From your example, it's not clear what delimits the array elements here. It's also not clear what "to sort by the name 'john'" means. Could you please clarify?

Comment: The code given in the OP does not match the question, please edit

Answer (score 2):

I have used the sortBy() function from underscore.js to sort arrays and it worked OK for me: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#sortBy

If Matthias Benkard's answer doesn't solve your problem, check out underscore.js

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement is a bit vague, but in general, you can sort an array using some function that extracts the key to be sorted on (I'll call this function `key` here) by using something like the following:

```
array.sort(function(x, y) {
  var x_key = key(x);
  var y_key = key(y);
  return (x_key < y_key ? -1 : x_key === y_key ? 0 : 1);
});
```

In your case, `key` would have to be a function that extracts the name from an array element.

If your array elements are strings, you might want to try regular expressions:

```
var key = function(x) {
  return /<img[^>]*>([^<]*)<br>/.exec(x)[1];
};
```

Comment: how would you go on about implementing the key function